# How to Pass the array values on query string in php

Tags: php, arrays, query-string

I need your help.,

How to pass the array values in query string...

```
<?php 
                foreach ( $Cart->getItems() as $order_code=>$quantity ) :
                $pname[]= $Cart->getItemName($order_code);
                $item[]= $Cart->getItemPrice($order_code);
                $qty[]=$quantity;
                endforeach;
                ?>
                <form action='expresscheckout.php?amt=<?php echo $total_price; ?>&item_name=<?php echo $pname; ?>&unit=<?php echo $item; ?>&quan=<?php echo $qty; ?>' METHOD='POST'>
<input type='image' name='submit' src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif' border='0' align='top' alt='Check out with PayPal'/>
</form>
```

This is my code sample.,for the above sample code i have to pass the query string on my action url that is expresscheckout.php?amt=100.,etc...values are coming under the $pname[],$item[],$qty[].

**Expecting output** in expresscheckout.php

expresscheckout.php?pname=product1,product2&item=item1,item2&qty=1,2,3....like this....

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you just need to use PHP's [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to turn an array into a comma-separated list. i.e. for the $item array:

```
$item = array('item1', 'item2');
echo implode(',', $item);
```

Will output:

```
item1,item2
```

So, something like this should print a querystring similar to what you want:

```
echo 'pname='.implode(',', $pname).
     '&item='.implode(',', $item).
     '&qty='.implode(',', $qty);
```

Comment: - There is simple method to do this check my answer .

Comment: No worries, I do know what a serialized variable is. OP wanted the query string in the format I provided. BTW, what you've submitted isn't urlencoded, but I wouldn't recommend passing serialized PHP via URLs in any case.

Comment: may i know, why serialization is not recommendable ? just for curious

Comment: Horrible URLs (i.e. the opposite of RESTful) that aren't cross-platform, and from a security perspective given PHP's dynamic typing it would greatly complicate input validation. Persisting complex data structures is what sessions are for, URLs are meant to be resource IDs and not to have PHP, SQL or other programming code in them. There's nothing strictly illegal about have a single querystring variable that's urlencoded serialized PHP, it's just not good practice.

Answer (score 10):

To pass the array values you should use [ ].
For ex.

```
<form method="post" action="path to script">
<input type="checkbox" id="colors[]" value="red" /> Red
<input type="checkbox" id="colors[]" value="blue" /> Blue
<input type="checkbox" id="colors[]" value="green" /> Green
<input type="checkbox" id="colors[]" value="yellow" /> Yellow
</form>
```

And you need to use like this in PHP

```
$colors=$_POST['colors']; //takes the data from a post operation...
$query=INSERT INTO colors VALUES('$colors');
```

Comment: I'm sure AjayR knows this, but for those reading this answer:

Never directly set unescaped values into a SQL statement like shown. It's just a simplification to avoid putting a bunch of code in the answer that doesn't relate directly to the question.

Comment: Yes Micheal, I just shown the code for simplicity, we need to take care of SQL injection and other things before inserting in to database.

Answer (score -1):

You need to serialize your array

**serializing in php**

> Generates a storable representation of
>   a value
>
> This is useful for storing or passing
>   PHP values around without losing their
>   type and structure.
>
> To make the serialized string into a
>   PHP value again, use unserialize().

ref :-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Example

```
$my_array= (array('val1', 'val2','val3');

server.php?query_string=serialize($my_array)
```

in server page

```
$query_string= unserialize($_REQUEST['query_string']);
```

Now it will be in array format

I hope this Helps you