# Getting array param out of query string with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, query-string, querystringparameter

(**NOTE:** This is a follow up to a previous question, [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974820/how-to-pass-the-array-values-on-query-string-in-php), where I asked about standard methods for passing arrays within query strings.)

I now have some PHP code that needs to consume the said query string- What kind of query string array formats does PHP recognize, and do I have to do anything special to retrieve the array?

The following doesn't seem to work:

**Query string:**

```
?formparts=[a,b,c]
```

**PHP:**

```
$myarray = $_GET["formparts"];
echo gettype($myarray)
```

**result:**

```
string
```

Comment: next time try to explain better your question, because as now it's unreadable

Comment: There's only one type of array in php, an "array". The format depends on what you put into them.

Comment: @yes123, @MarcB- please see revised question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query string should rather look like this:

```
?formparts[]=a&formparts[]=b&formparts[]=c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a query string, you are looking at the `$_GET` variable. This will contain everything after the `?` in your previous question.

So what you will have to do is pretty much the opposite of the other question.

```
$products = array();
// ... Add some checking of $_GET to make sure it is sane
....
// then assign..
$products = explode(',', $_GET['pname']);
```

and so on for each variable. I must give you a full warning here, you MUST check what comes through the `$_GET` variable to make sure it is sane. Otherwise you risk having your site compromised.

Comment: @KyleWppd- I'm talking about passing arrays WITHIN query strings, not the query string GET array itself- See @soulmerge's answer

Comment: By definition in PHP, and variable passed as part of a `$_GET` or `$_POST` request is a string. I can't speak to whether `soulmerge`'s answer will work or not, but he is using a different syntax to assign into the array than you are.